# DBTable creates new row instead off updating the existing

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I try to update an DB entry with now data, but i am just creating an new entry:

```
$client =$this->clientTable->find($id);
$client->CompanyName = $request->getPost('CompanyName');
$this->clientTable->update();
$this->_redirect('client/index');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::find()** method returns **Zend_Db_Table_Rowset object**. You should use method which will return you **Zend_Db_Table_Row object** and use it.

For example:

```
$clientRow = $this->clientTable->fetchRow(array('id' => $id));
$clientRow->CompanyName = $request->getPost('CompanyName');
$clientRow->save();
```

If your's table primary key name is not '**id**', change it to suitable value in the first line of code above.